# Tableview cell is reloaded multiple table cell each time when its loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im making a fetch request as follows,

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"PendingShipmentDetails"];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

then im adding the fetched records to an array as follows within `viewDidLoad` method...

```
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (result.count > 0) {
        int i;
        amountArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        statusArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        shipmentReferenceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        invoiceNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (i = 0; i < [result count]; i++) {
            pending = (NSManagedObject *)[result objectAtIndex:i];
            [shipmentReferenceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"shipmentno"]];
            [invoiceNumberArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"invoice_no"]];
            [amountArray addObject:[pending valueForKey:@"amount"]];
            [statusArray addObject: [pending valueForKey:@"status"]];
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"SORRY");
    }
```

The problem is that, since adding the objects within for loop, the table cell is being populated with same value multiple times each time when Im navigating towards it. However if im adding the elements to array, outside the for loop, only one element is being added and hence only one table cell is visible at anytime. How can I get this issue sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going in quite wrong direction
Instead of using for loop you can use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

```
[ChildList enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        Child = (ChildListModel*)[[ObjectBuilder builder] objectFromJSON:obj className:NSStringFromClass([ChildListModel class])];

        if (Child) {
            [originalList addObject:Child];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: whats the childlist and child?

Comment: here childlist is [pending valueForKey:@"amount"] and child is object of my model

Comment: can you please elobrate? what is childlistmodel then

Comment: Its my model class ... i get the data in my model format
instead of that u can use arr or dic

Answer (score 0):

Once all the elements are added in array then reload tableView,So it will return the row count as count of the array and will populated data once for each.

Comment: reloading makes all tablecells invisible

Comment: At the time of reloading table,just check how many rows being returned by using breakpoint.

Comment: Apply breakpoint on tableView delegate method "numberOfRowsInSection" and check how many rows are being return through the arrayCount.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSArray *)fetchCoreData 
{

    AppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PendingShipmentDetails" inManagedObjectContext:app.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError * error;
    NSArray * fetchedObjects = [app.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Saved Data %@", fetchedObjects);

    if (fetchedObjects != nil) {
        return fetchedObjects;
    }else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Try this ... i have this method fetchCoreData in my modal class. And this works perfectly for me.

Add the fetched data to array.